# Reposition Spotlight search bar to its default location in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, spotlight, mojave

I accidentally dragged and moved the Spotlight search bar shown on pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. This is what it looks like now:

[image: Spotlight screenshot]

I want to re-center it, but I am not very sure how to do it precisely. Is there a way or a setting to move it back to its original location again?

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.

Comment: Thank you @NimeshNeema for the correct term. I didn't notice yet that it is called Spotlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with OS X El Capitan 10.11, it became possible to freely drag and move around Spotlight search bar.

To reposition it to its original location, simply tap and hold on the Spotlight search button in the Menu bar (shown towards right) for a couple seconds. This should do the trick!

[image]

Comment: Wow! It was so simple yet, not easy to guess. This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Since El Capitan, you can move the Spotlight bar/window. Just
>   click-and-drag it to wherever you want.

Comment: When quoting content from somewhere else, always provide a link back to the source. If your answer is identical to another on the site, perhaps the question should be marked as duplicate? If not, please tailor your answer to the specific question being asked, thanks.